# How do you convert a list of nested lists into a list of lists with unique data?

Tags: python, unique, nested-lists

After looping my brains out creating reference dictionaries and multi-nested lookup lists I've decided that there has to be an easier way to do this. I can't be the first person to do this type of conversion. I don't even know where to start looking in the docs for a solution.

I have a system that is outputting the following data.

```
initial_data = [
    [21,[[1],[2,3],[6],[7]]],
    [22,[[4,5],[6,7]],
    [23,[[1],[4,5],[6],[7]]],
    [24,[[1],[2,3,4],[6],[7]]],
]
```

I have another system that expects the data in the following format (order does not matter).

```
return_data = [
    [21,[1,2,6,7]],
    [21,[1,3,6,7]],
    [22,[4,6]],
    [22,[4,7]],
    [22,[5,6]],
    [22,[5,7]],
    [23,[1,4,6,7]],
    [23,[1,5,6,7]],
    [24,[1,2,6,7]],
    [24,[1,3,6,7]],
    [24,[1,4,6,7]],
]
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Please share your code and error if any

Comment: @depperm I tried for hours to think up a solution on my own and perusing SO without any luck.

Comment: @DineshPundkar I don't see a reason to share failed attempts at looping through fake data.

Comment: @Jeremy - Failed attempts should be posted since it will help others to understand problem more. I really appreciate that you already tried multiple times and then posted the question. However, there are cases when people post question to complete their homework (want us to write code for them) and SO condemn that kind of attitude. That's why people ask to show your efforts.Please check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `itertools.product`, which produces

> Cartesian product of input iterables.
>
> Roughly equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression. For
>   example, product(A, B) returns the same as ((x,y) for x in A for y in
>   B).

Use it on the second element of each sublist should produce what you need:

```
from itertools import product
[[k, p] for k, v in initial_data for p in product(*v)]

# [[21, (1, 2, 6, 7)],
#  [21, (1, 3, 6, 7)],
#  [22, (4, 6)],
#  [22, (4, 7)],
#  [22, (5, 6)],
#  [22, (5, 7)],
#  [23, (1, 4, 6, 7)],
#  [23, (1, 5, 6, 7)],
#  [24, (1, 2, 6, 7)],
#  [24, (1, 3, 6, 7)],
#  [24, (1, 4, 6, 7)]]
```